# Align two different structures with respect to their active sites or heme cofactor

Tags: pdb, pymol

I have two enzymes, with heme cofactors. but their overall structure is very different.

I use Pymol regularly to visualize protein pdb structures.

I want to align both structures, but the structures don't align well due to very low homology. However, their active sites/substrate entrance channels may be more similar than the rest of the structure.
so,

1. I want to align only the substrate channels from both enzymes and compare their structure.
   or
2. align both proteins only using the heme as a reference point. So both hemes from two enzymes align and then I can manually do the rest.

I am more interested in how the substrate would be accessible in both enzymes differently.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry for being a bit unclear. We can pick two proteins like cytochrome P450 BM3 with pdb id 6H1L or 6H1O. The second protein can be a similar peroxygenase UPO, e.g. 7pn4.
Thanks.

Comment: @terdon , do the same rules of SO apply to Bioinformatics , the question seems too wide , at least irfan could have named two pdbs code as inputs, toghrther with the aa defining the channels  to have us to try to get a result with

Comment: If you feel the question is too broad, then ask for clarifications and/or vote to close as "needs more focus". That said, I don't see why this is too broad: the main question here is "given two pdb structures, how can I align and compare only specific parts of those structures instead?" which seems like it should be answerable by those working with this kind of data.

Comment: Please add more context to this question; be as specific as possible about the problem you're struggling with. Example proteins, or other input files, are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

OK, trying to answer question 2, think I need to be sure that both enzymes have same identical heme cofactor and then find a rotation/translation matrix that applied to heme of protein A moved exactly on top of heme of protein B , than I have to move the entire protein backbone of protein A using that matrix, is it reasonable ? Am I getting it wrong ? With **PyMOL** I tried to use `Pair/Pair_fit` command with two heme proteins :
`2d0t` ([https://www.rcsb.org/structure/2d0t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVUTq.png) and `4zv8` ([https://www.rcsb.org/structure/4ZV8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAsRi.png)) :

`pair hem_2d0t , hem_4zv8,`  same as `pair_fit hem_2d0t , hem_4zv8`, where `hem_2d0t`,`hem_4zv8`  are the heme of the two proteins [`select model 2d0t and resn HEM` and `set_name sele, hem_2d0t` or `select hem_2d0t, model 2d0t and resn HEM`].

See results, superposed heme:

[image]

Superposed Proteins :

[image]

As for question 1 I tried to answer using the tools available to me.
I picked the two same proteins : `2d0t` ([https://www.rcsb.org/structure/2d0t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVUTq.png) and `4zv8` ([https://www.rcsb.org/structure/4ZV8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAsRi.png)). Using `parKVFinder` ([https://github.com/LBC-LNBio/parKVFinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqzr4.png) , [https://www.softxjournal.com/article/S2352-7110(20)30319-8/fulltext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73rfc.png)) **pymol plugin** on both proteins stripped of all their HETATM, I calculated their cavities. As an example , here a png of `2d0t`  cavities :

[image]

Then I extracted the residues surrounding the cavity using :

`select model 2d0t_merged near_to 5.0 of resn KAF` ; [named `sele_2d0t`]

`select model 4zv8_merged near_to 5.0 of resn KAB` ; [named `sele_4zv8`]

being `KAF` and `KAB` cavities described as non_bounded atom in pdb format as output of `parKVFinder` .
I believe `parKVFinder` has is own output for the residues surrounding cavities, but wanted to try `PyMOL`

Example for `2d0t` :

[image]

Then I used

`cealign sele_4zv8 , sele_2d0t` (https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Cealign) to align the residues of the two cavities. (`cealign` uses just CA of the selections provided).

Results , only cavities and surrounding residues :

[image]

the two heme protein cavities are not alignrd even if the HIS (2dt0, red)  and CYS (4zv8, yellow) are on the same side :

[image]

NOTE:

2dt0 in magenta

4zv8 in cyan

I choose 2 different heme protein (could be more extreme though) , just because the question was open to broad attempts, could be interesting too see for example results on not too distant cytochromes

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to follow the process and report back.